# r: Adding columns to dataframe in function called by for-loop

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to build up a dataframe within my function `myfunction` by calling it within a for-loop.

It looks like this

```
df = data.frame("Indices" = c("a", "b"))

myfunction = function(i){
    df = cbind(df, as.data.frame(rbind(i,i^2)))
}

for(i in 1:10){
  myfunction(i)
}
```

My aim is to add one more column to the `df` through each iteration of the for-loop. **But** unfortunately `df` simply stays empty (i.e. no further columns are being added).

So, in the end it should look something like this:

```
V1 V1 V1 V1 V1 V1 V1 V1 V1  V1
a  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
b  1  4  9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add `df <- ` in your loop. You forgot to assign anything.

Comment: For this particular example there is no need for the loop construct... e.g. `df <- cbind(df, as.data.frame(rbind(1:n,(1:n)^2)))`

Comment: `mylist = lapply(setNames(1:10, 1:10), function(i) c(i, i^2)); df[names(mylist)] = mylist` or `df = cbind(df, mylist)` for the last step.

Comment: @JosephWood please post `cbind(df, rbind(1:n,(1:n)^2))` as an answer. As the current answers are teaching bad practices of both growing objects in loops and using loops on vecotrized operations.

Comment: may I ask why this is put on hold? I mean, it should be ok to ask a question like this, or not?

Comment: @coffeinjunky: I am asking the question in a very minimalistic and simple way, but both, the loop AND the function are of need for what I want to do finally! I am aware that one could of course solve the above problem in way suggested by JosephWood or Frank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or if you want to use a function, here is what you can do:

```
df = data.frame("Indices" = c("a", "b"))

myfunction = function(i, df){
    return(cbind(df, as.data.frame(rbind(i,i^2))))
}

for(i in 1:10){
    df=myfunction(i, df)
}

> df
  Indices V1 V1 V1 V1 V1 V1 V1 V1 V1  V1
i       a  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
        b  1  4  9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100
```

When we call functions and we want to have changes back from the function, we should take care of Call by Reference or Call by Value cases. There reason why your function does not work because you Call your function by Value. Thus, the changes inside your function is independent of the current scope in which you are.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into scoping problems.

When you change df inside your function, this will not change anything outside your function. There's lots of ways of solving this, easiest is probably to just get rid of the function.

```
for(i in 1:10){
  df = cbind(df, as.data.frame(rbind(i,i^2)))
}
```

Comment: Growing objects in a loop is not a good practice either. I wouldn't post that as an answer.